# What's a good local database with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

What would be a good choice for a local database to use with Entity Framework for an WPF application that needs local database.

I dont want to use MSSQL Server cos that'd be an overkill and or MSSQL CE cos few days back I was using SQL CE 3.5 and had all sorts of issues of  it not supporting server generated IDs.

I've read MS Access has issues as well. and dont want to use SQLite either.

TIA

Comment: Fyi, EF does NOT support MS Access.

Answer (score 6):

[SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) sounds a good fit to me.

Comment: Yes but the installer for that is 235MB, total over kill for my little app. Plus I gotta take care of installing it as well. Would you have any other suggestion? TIA

Comment: If it's that small an app, why not use Linq to XML?

Comment: @user109134 235Mb - that's the version with mgmt tools. Database-only is 71Mb (32-bit) and 74Mb (64-bit). If you're going to use EF, SQL Server really is the best choice.  
  
If you want to use a small local file-based db, go with Jet (access) and plain old ADO.NET+OLEDB.

Comment: There's also the Compact edition with many fewer features but a lightweight installer.

Answer (score 0):

What about [MySQL Embedded](http://www.mysql.com/oem/)?
You can use either EF provider by Devart (it is a part of [dotConnect for MySQL Professional](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/)), or the provider integrated into [MySQL Connector /NET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net.html).